# In-app billingservice onServiceConnected() not called on 4.0/ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, in-app-billing

My app has a single in-app purchase, and is modeled after the Dungeons sample that Google provides (viewable at http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/).  The only difference is that the code to restore transactions on the first run has been separated out and placed in my app's main activity.  (My modified "Dungeons" activity is where the user goes to purchase the plugin)

The `restoreTransactions()` code in my main activity's `onCreate()` works great on both a 2.3 and 1.6 test device:

```
    if (!initialized) 
    {
        BillingService mBillingService = new BillingService();
        mBillingService.setContext(this);

        if (mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) 
        {
            mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
        }

        mBillingService.unbind();
    }
```

However on a wifi-Xoom running 4.0.4, it seems to plow right through it without actually doing anything, *until* I open up my "Dungeons" activity, at which point everything which was supposed to happen in the main activity, happens (almost like it queues everything up but waits for something in "Dungeons" before actually acting on it).

Digging deeper I can see that `onServiceConnected()` in BillingService.java is never called on the Xoom until I open my "Dungeons" activity, whereas it's called just fine on 2.3 & 1.6 without opening the same activity.

Has something changed in 4.x that is preventing this from working the way it does on earlier versions?

Comment: the same happens to me too.. i am looking into it now, if i come across a solution, will let you know

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'm still fighting with this one.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I'm hoping the problem will go away once I update to the newer IAP implementation, but my day job is preventing me from getting around to that.