# Issues with onServiceConnected and ICS

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing

So I'm currently trying to implement in-app purchases in the game android game I've been working on, and am having some troubles.

Basically, the in-app purchase will be to remove ads. So when the game starts, it connects the billing service, and when that gets the onServiceConnected callback it goes ahead and checks if the user has purchased the ad removal. If not, then it initialises the ad mob stuff etc.

The problem I've been having is that onServiceConnected never executes when I run the application on my ICS 4.0.3 device. It works fine on my 2.3.4 device.

I've checked the logcat output and set breakpoints, and there's nothing there.

Does anyone know of any issues or changes that occurred in ICS that may be relevant?

Also, I found this similar question, but it had no answers, and that was a good 6 months ago [[In-app billingservice onServiceConnected() not called on 4.0/ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255735/in-app-billingservice-onserviceconnected-not-called-on-4-0-ics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255735/in-app-billingservice-onserviceconnected-not-called-on-4-0-ics)

EDIT: Ok, so I worked out that on my ICS device the bindService call is returning FALSE, and returning TRUE on other devices when it works. So my question now is why is it returning false? I read briefly somewhere that it is to do with the Intent not resolving to a Service or some such?